# AngularJs-Material como alterar a lingua para portugues do md-datepicker

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

Estou tentando trocar a linguagem do md-datepicker para português pois os dias da semana e o meses estão em inglês, portanto fica confuso para o usuário... Existe alguma forma de trocar esta linguagem? Formatar os campos para Português? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`<div flex-gt-xs>
         <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
                            <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>

</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para corrigir as datas é necessário configurar o $mdDateLocaleProvider

fica dessa forma:

`.config(function($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
   $mdDateLocaleProvider.shortMonths  = ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abril','Maio', 'Jun', 'Jul','Ago', 'Set', 'Out','Nov','Dez'];
   $mdDateLocaleProvider.Months  = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril','Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho','Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'];
   $mdDateLocaleProvider.days = ['Domingo','Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta','Sexta', 'Sabado'];
   $mdDateLocaleProvider.shortDays = ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q','S','S'];
  });`